# Not able to launch Online Apps (facebook etc.) on AVD emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, selendroid

I am trying to launch online apps but not able to launch them on the emulator. While offline apps (Selendroid test app, Offline Dictionaries etc.) are able to launch on the AVD emulator.
Please let me know What could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

By strictly guessing, you're trying to install applications with native libraries compiled for arm on an x86 image - which means you have to download the proper APK, or switch to an arm image.

If that's not the case, please add additional information like which image you are using, how you're trying to install the application and what the error is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the problem with the apk. I am using the x86 AVD emulator and that's why it wasn't working. When tried with VLC and flipkart apk, it's working fine. 
But I am facing the problem of internet connectivity now for my emulator. I have set the proxy and port number as well but it's still not connecting. I have 2 different emulators, one of them supports upto Kitkat and another supports only Marshmallow. The proxy settings are working fine for Kitkat but when set for Marshmallow, it's not working. Is there anything I can do regarding this. Thanks.